# Remove content in specific cell when using auto-inserted content in row using @{}

Tags: tables

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{r @{\,--\,} l}
   \toprule
          &       \\
   \midrule
     8:10 &  8:55 \\
     8:55 &  9:40 \\
    10:00 & 10:45 \\
    10:45 & 11:30 \\
    11:30 & 12:00 \\
    12:40 & 13:25 \\
    13:25 & 14:10 \\
    14:25 & 15:10 \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I remove the first endash (i.e., the one between `\toprule` and `\midrule`) without changing the rest of the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\multicolumn` command completely over-rides the header for a cell or cells

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{r @{\,--\,} l}
   \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
   \midrule
     8:10 &  8:55 \\
     8:55 &  9:40 \\
    10:00 & 10:45 \\
    10:45 & 11:30 \\
    11:30 & 12:00 \\
    12:40 & 13:25 \\
    13:25 & 14:10 \\
    14:25 & 15:10 \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This can be used not only here but for example to have a one-off cell alignment, to skip insertions using the `array` package `>` syntax, *etc.*